# Data storage management

Tags: java

I have a task to create a store system. The language that I use to program is Java and the information MUST to be saved in the pc where the program runs.

As far as I know Access does that perfectly when it comes to Visual Basic since I can use the Access interface and edit some cdoe with VB.

Another option I thought of is creating some kind of my own import/export system that will save the information into files and loads them when needed which will require a lot of extra coding.

So what should I do? What is the best way to do that with Java?

Comment: This depends entirely on your use case. There an uncountable SQL, noSQL, serialization, xml etc... based solutions out there. Voting to close as not a real question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to do it would probably be to use an SQL database such as sqlite or mysql, but it depends a lot on what sort of system you're designing. Options are really,

- SQL Database (such as sqlite)
- NoSQL Database (such as couchdb)
- Object serialization. You could just serialize objects and dump them to files.

Do you need to handle concurrency with multiple programs reading and writing to the database? Do you need low risk of data loss or corruption, or could you sacrifice some data safety for a quick and easy implementation? Do you need to store a lot of data or just some? How fast does it need to be accessed, and is it accessed all at once or do you need to query certain things?

We'd really need answers to all of those questions to be able to give you a good answer for what's best.

Comment: It's a simple program that handles orders/clients/stock etc.. It's a project that will serve a very small company with not a lot of clients and orders.

Comment: I want to add something. I would like to be able to run the program in every pc which means SQL is not relevant since it needs to be installed and configured.

Comment: That also means Access wouldn't be relevant, since technically it's something you'd have to install. If you can't install any database applications and Java wrappers/libraries to access them, I think you're going to be limited to object serialization or some sort of XML storage.

Comment: But access comes with microsoft office which is installed on 99% of pc's definitely on office pc's, and would I be able to use the access interface with java?if not I guess object serialization would be the way I'll choose.

Comment: Yes, you can access Access from Java. Google how to use JDBC with Microsoft Access and you should find some tutorials (like this one: http://www.javacodehelp.com/java-tutorial/DatabaseExamples.html)